# cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Windows.Forms.Datagridviewcell c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to do something like if there is a selection from a drop downbox it should make a change in color to the Datagridview row.

I have used switch case, doent change nothing, hence I wanted to use another approach to it. Code looks like this

```
private void RowsColor()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1 != null)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells != null)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11] != null)
                        {
                            //string val = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                            var val = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11];
                            if (val = "Confirm Appointment")
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }
                            else if (val = "Reschedule")
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    } 
}
```

Now I am getting something like this as an error

> cannot implicitly convert type string to
>   System.Windows.Forms.Datagridviewcell

New to this, What exactly am I missing?

Comment: In which line ?

Comment: @farbiondriven if (val = "Confirm Appointment") and else if (val = "Reschedule")

Comment: @Thomas `val` is type of `Datagridviewcell` determined at complied time but you are comparing it to string

Comment: @Thomas use the previous commented line `var val = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();` if you are sure about them being string

Answer (score 0):

Decomment

```
string val = "";
try{
    val = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
   }
catch(NullReferenceException ex){
   val = "Not yet set"
}
```

and

```
if (val.Equals("Confirm Appointment"))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
else if (val.Equals( "Reschedule"))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
```

Comment: throws Exception on string val = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

Comment: Which exception ?

Comment: NullreferenceException object reference not set to an instance of an object, been battling with it all day!

Comment: ooooh ! this means there is no string in that cell !

Comment: how do i get it to get a string then? guess thats why its been struggling with me since today. I made a method to create a dropdown which it did, now i want it to use the values in the Cell to make comparism

Comment: This depends on what your code is trying to achieve, and how the dataGridView is filled in the first place. You can set a default value of that cell when you are filling it in your program.

Comment: i am making a visitor system, that when the drop downbox is selected, it saves to another table in the Mysql database and changes the row of the row to red.

Comment: Yes but when you start the program, how do you populate the dropdowns in the first place ?

Comment: like this cmn.Items.Add("Please Select");